# Save PDF file using PHPPdf

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using [**PHPPdf**](https://github.com/psliwa/PHPPdf) library to generate PDFs on the fly in my Symfony2 app. However I could not find a way to dump/write/save PDF raw data to a file.

From Symfony controller I tried this:

```
$content = $this->render('AcmeBundle:PDF:template.xml.twig');
file_put_contents('documents/123.pdf', $content);
```

but as it seems I get rendered HTML and not PDF binary data. When I add `@Pdf` annotation all output is being routed to PDF document and into browser but I need to save raw data instead for later retrieval.

I looked into `FacadeBuilder` but coudln't find anything useful.

Any help would be much appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/psliwa/PdfBundle/blob/master/Controller/ExampleController.php#L28), I think you should use `$content = $facade->render($xml);` like in the example action.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly that I was looking for - thanks a lot! :) I was too busy looking all over the library just to miss `ExampleController` :|